# Python: Print first two characters of each item in a list. (without spaces)

Tags: python, python-2.7, split

Code so far:

```
fullname = "John Doe"
namelist = fullname.split()
for word in namelist:
    print word[:2].lower(),
```

This outputs:

```
jo do
```

I want it to output:

```
jodo
```

Any and all suggestions welcomed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `print` "magic comma" always inserts spaces, so you can't do things this way.

You have three choices:

1. [Join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the words up into a string first, then print that string: `print ''.join(word[:2].lower() for word in namelist)`.
2. [Write](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write) directly to [`stdout`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdout) instead of using `print`: `sys.stdout.write(word[:2].lower())`
3. Use [Python 3-style `print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), which *can* do things this way. First, `from __future__ import print_function` at the top of your code. Then, `print(word[:2].lower(), end='')`.

Comment: @twasbrillig: Actually, I usually avoid it if I'm writing 2.x-specific code, because it tends to make people think I'm writing 2.x/3.x code and complain when it doesn't work in 3.x. Then again, I haven't written any new 2.x-specific code in a few years, so…

Answer (score 4):

The comma creates a space.  Try creating a list comprehension and joining it with empty string:

```
>>> print "".join(word[:2].lower() for word in namelist)
jodo
```

To see how it's working in smaller steps:

```
>>> firsts = [word[:2].lower() for word in namelist]
>>> firsts
['jo', 'do']
>>> print "".join(firsts)
jodo
```

Comment: For the record, `"A".join(myList)` is the reverse of `myString.split("A")`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> fullname = "John Doe"
>>> words = fullname.lower().split()
>>> words
['john', 'doe']
>>> print("".join(x[:2] for x in words))
jodo
```

[:2] selects 1st two letter . `lower` converts them to lowercase.using `+` you can concatenate string.

python 2.x:

```
>>> print "".join(x[:2] for x in words)
```

Comment: Why are you explaining the part of the code he's already written, instead of the part you added to fix his problem?

Comment: any reason for downvoting????, if downvote plz provide reason so one should correct it

Comment: This makes the code less general because it now only works for 2-word names, no more and no less.

Comment: its not about general check OP what he asked for

Comment: @Hackaholic: To be fair, the title is "Print first two characters of each item in a list"; just because the example happens to only have two elements in the list doesn't mean his real code does. So twasbrillig may have a point.

Comment: @Hackaholic, by your logic a program of `print(jodo)` would be a correct answer too.

Comment: OK, but now it's effectively the same as dkamins's answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [print function from Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) has a parameter `sep` (for "separator") which can be set to a null string. Using that and using the `*` operator to specify passing in a variable number of arguments:

```
from __future__ import print_function
fullname = "John Doe"
words = (word[:2].lower() for word in fullname.split())
print(*words, sep='')
```